# kioslave5 high cpu usage

Tags: kde, kde-neon

```
└─$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="KDE neon 5.27"
NAME="KDE neon"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="5.27"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=neon
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
HOME_URL="https://neon.kde.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://neon.kde.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kde.org/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://kde.org/privacypolicy/"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

respawning kioslave5 process eating 12% of processor and 100M of memory, can't kill it. It seems not a virus activity, but why? I need this 12% of processor, please tell me what to do?